# javascript-trigger function 2 times when onclick check box

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML Code :

```
<div id="txtAge">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="checking()" id="ch1" value="1"><td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="checking()" id="ch2" value="10"><td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="checking()" id="ch3" value="12"><td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="checking()" id="ch4" value="3"><td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="checking()" id="ch5" value="221"><td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="checking()" id="ch6" value="130"><td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="checking()" id="ch7" value="132"><td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="checking()" id="ch8" value="3333"><td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    </div>
```

Javascript :

```
function checking(){
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
            $(this).closest('tr').find('input').not(this).prop('checked', true);
            alert(this.value);
        });
}
```

This is my code. when i click the checkbox it alert one times, when i click other checkbox it alert 2 times.Why the onclick function trigger more than 1 time when i continue clicking the checkbox?

Here the demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/L9z9t04p/11/

Comment: Remove `onclick="checking()"` from your HTML.

Comment: @RayonDabre As I said to gurvinder372, in this case the function wouldn't be called at all as jQuery binder is placed inside that function, ... So this is not a full answer!

Comment: @neoselcev, I did not claim is as an answer..Just a hint ;)

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/L9z9t04p/17/

Comment: i dun know why your code does not work for me..actually the table is created by javascript after successful ajax call..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `onclick="checking"` as an inline attribute from the checkbox.

Both are going to run independently and you can add as many event listeners to an element as you want, so one will not automatically remove the other.

Also remove this checking method too, you can directly bind `jquery.on` event

```
       $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
            $(this).closest('tr').find('input').not(this).prop('checked', true);
            alert(this.value);
        });
```

or if you don't want to remove `checking` method and will call it on some condition then you need to ensure that `checking` method is invoked

```
function checking(){
$('input[type="checkbox"]').off('change' ); //if the checking() is called multiple times
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
            $(this).closest('tr').find('input').not(this).prop('checked', true);
            alert(this.value);
        });
}
checking();
```

Comment: This is not the full answer. He has his jQuery binder inside function, which wouldn't be called in case he'll remove that attribute.

Comment: @max-cheng I have updated the answer to address the concern raised in comments.

Comment: @ gurvinder372 it will checked all the checkbox instead of one.http://jsfiddle.net/L9z9t04p/18/

Comment: @maxcheng what should it do then instead?

Comment: @ gurvinder372  my intention is one row only one checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 1):

The problem arise from the fact that you are binding `change` event handler on every inline change event handler. this will keep on adding an event handler and you will keep on getting multiple `alert`s in this case.

Remove the inline `change` event handler from your check box. As you are already binding it using jQuery.

*HTML*

```
<input type="checkbox" id="ch5" value="221">
```

*Script*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('input').not(this).prop('checked', true);
        alert(this.value);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Whether you bind the event through a listener:

```
 $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
```

Or you do inline binding to a function:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" onclick="checking()" id="ch2" value="10"><td>
```

Don't perform both. What's happening is that, everytime you click on the checkbox, you are registering the function one more time to the event. So every click will alert one more time that the last time

Answer (score 0):

For each time you trigger the function checking, you're adding an event to all checkboxes. It will accumulate for each time you click. I tried this in your fiddle and it works:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    alert(this.value);
  });
});
```

Also, remove the onclick call on your checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

remove onclick="checking()" from html and bind change event for check box only once